# Forcing ActiveRelation to use rails cache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2, dalli

I have a `languages` table that hardly every changes. I am trying to avoid database queries on this table other the initial caching.

```
class Language < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :code, :name, :native_name

  def self.find_by_name_in_cache(name)
    get_all_cached.find {|l| l.name == name}
  end

  def self.find_by_code_in_cache(code)
    get_all_cached.find {|l| l.code == code}
  end

  def self.find_by_id_in_cache(id)
    get_all_cached.find {|l| l.id == id}
  end

  def self.get_all_cached
    Rails.cache.fetch('all_languages') {Language.all}
  end
end
```

All goes fine as long as I am using one of the `find_in_cache` methods that I have defined.

My question is, how can I force `ActiveRelation` to use the caching as well.

For example, consider the following user model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :native_language, :class_name => :Language, :foreign_key => :native_language_id
end
```

When I access `@user.native_language`, it queries `language` from the database. I would highly appreciate any ideas to prevent this.

I know I can do the following:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :native_language, :class_name => :Language, :foreign_key => :native_language_id

  def native_language_cached
    Language.find_by_id_in_cache(self.native_language_id)
  end
end
```

However, I was hoping for a more transparent solution as a lot of my tables reference `languages` table and it would be so messy to add the `cached` methods to all these models.

Comment: see if this gem helps https://github.com/Shopify/identity_cache

Comment: @AJcodez, thanks for the gem, its a nice gem. Its basically a generic implementation of the `find_in_cache` and `cached` methods that I added, so it saves me from repeating those in each model. However, it is as intrusive as my solution. I have to use the `cache` methods instead of default active record methods.

Comment: I mean you have to use different methods, but you don't want the default active record functionality so you probably can't be using the default active record moethds

Comment: Makes sense, would you please submit as an answer so I can give you credit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To cache the query during a single request, you don't have to do anything besides make sure you're using the `ActiveRecord::QueryCache` middleware. If you call it twice:

```
2.times{ user.native_language.to_s }
```

You'll see something like this in your log:

```
Language Load (0.2ms)   SELECT `languages`.* FROM `languages` WHERE ...
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `languages`.* FROM `languages` WHERE ...
```

Caching across requests requires manual caching. The [identity_cache](https://github.com/Shopify/identity_cache) gem might be useful for what you're trying to do (cache associations).

The quickest way would probably just to add the `expires_in` option to the code you have. You can write a generic `cached_find` method like the following:

```
def self.cached_find(id)
  key = model_name.cache_key + '/' + id
  Rails.cache.fetch(key) do
    find(id).tap do |model|
      Rails.cache.write(key, model, expires_in: cache_period)
    end
  end
end

def self.cache_period
  3.days
end
```

You can make it a module mixin to use with as many models as necessary. It does mean you have to write your own association finds. You can also do it with callbacks:

```
after_commit do
  Rails.cache.write(cache_key, self, expires_in: self.class.cache_period)
end
```